# Using custom properties with @page rules

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-variables, css-paged-media

I'm trying to use css custom properties together with @page rules, but it does not seem to work. It kind of make sense since css variables cascade and the `:root` selector and the @page rule don't have a child/parent relationship.

Below is a typical example of what I'd like to do:

```
:root {
    --page-width: 148.5mm;
    --page-height: 210mm;
}

@page  {
    size: var(--page-width) var(--page-height);
}
```

Is there any way I could use variables with @page rules?

Comment: Since `@page` is its own namespace, did you try `@page { :root {
 --page-width: 148.5mm; } }`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But then would there be a way to share the same variable between @page, and let's say, a div?

Comment: I don't think you can share between namespace's. Are you aware of that you can use @media query to set css rules when print?

Comment: @LGSon: You can't change the dimensions of a page using style rules, regardless of the media type. That's why the page at-rule exists.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for that note

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> css variables cascade and the `:root` selector and the @page rule don't have a child/parent relationship.

`@page` rules cascade, too. And [the page context does actually inherit from the root element](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page/#page-properties), which means not only do `@page` rules cascade, but they participate in the same cascade as style rules. But since this wasn't in the spec [a decade ago](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-css3-page-20061010), implementations where the page context doesn't inherit from the root element are still conformant to the spec.

While this means you shouldn't rely on `@page` rules inheriting custom properties from `:root`, it does also mean that `@page` itself accepts custom properties, essentially making inheritance a non-issue. So, the following is expected to work, but it doesn't — it seems that every browser fails to create the custom properties:

```
@page {
    --page-width: 148.5mm;
    --page-height: 210mm;
    size: var(--page-width) var(--page-height);
}
```

Interestingly, Firefox and Chrome have no trouble parsing *and* computing `var()` expressions *with fallback values* in `@page` style declarations, while Microsoft Edge fails to do so, which means the following will result in each page having 25mm margins in Firefox and Chrome:

```
@page {
    --page-margin: 50mm;
    margin: var(--page-margin, 25mm);
}
```

So, in short, custom properties in `@page` rules don't work — not because the spec doesn't allow it, but because every browser's implementation of custom properties is incomplete.