# why css variables won't work in @page rule

Tags: css, variables, printing, var

I've defined my css vars in root section as :

```css
:root {
  --print-size: A3 landscape;
  --print-margin: 50cm;
}

@media print {
  @page {
size: var(--print-size);
margin: var(--print-margin);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body onload="print()">
<h2>something to print</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why they does not take effect in my `@page` css rule.
e.g. print margin 50cm has no effect!

please help :-(

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735420/using-custom-properties-with-page-rules